# Procura em Index no MongoDB retornando palavras não existentes, 'Cama' acha 'Câmera'?

Tags: python, mongodb

Olá sou novo neste banco de dados e fiz o seguinte index para meus documentos:

```
produtos.create_index([('Tags', pymongo.TEXT)], unique=False, sparse=True,name='tags', default_language='portuguese')
```

então comando um find()

```
   db.getCollection('produtos').find({$text:{$search:'cama'}})
```

E ele me retorna um monte de smartphones como por exemplo um com essas tags:

```
"Tags" : [ 
        "iphone", 
        "64gb", 
        "dourado", 
        "tela", 
        "4.7", 
        "ios", 
        "4g", 
        "câmera", 
        "12mp", 
        "apple"
    ],
```

A única explicação esotérica que achei é o "câmera".  Apaguei o "Câmera" mas os "Cam" também estão sendo retornados.
Ele faz busca por chars ao invés de words?
Tentei o 'galax' e não retornou nenhum "Sansumg Galaxy". 
Porém 'ga' retorna placas mães como "Gigabytes', 'lga' ...
Estou perdido nessa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi do que você quer fazer, o operador `$search` da forma que está sendo usado não é o ideal pra esse caso. O `$search` vai quebrar a string passada em vários pedaços e fazer um `or` com todos esses pedaços. Ou seja, o que ele faz é uma tokenização da string de busca. A [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) do Mongo mostra esse comportamento.

Por exemplo, se você tiver: `db.times.find( { $text: { $search: "vasco vice" } } )`, ele vai retornar todos que contêm ou a string `"vasco"` ou `"vice"`. E caso queira que de fato a string inteira seja levada em consideração, `db.times.find( { $text: { $search: "\"vasco vice\"" } } )`

Outro ponto é que o `$text` pode ser case sensitive ou não, ele possui um parâmetro para tal, como consta na [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-operator-behavior).

Agora respondendo algumas de suas dúvidas, quando você buscou por `galax` a query não retornou `Sansumg Galaxy` porque provavelmente está case sensitive. E quando você pesquisou por `ga` ele retornou `Gigabytes` e `lga` pois ambas possuem o `ga`.

Comment: De fato nas leitura apressadas no começo da documentação esta lá "perform a text search of string content". Mas ainda fico pensando porque 'câmera' veio se 'cama' são diferentes. Porém já esta resolvido. Obrigado.